# How to use commons-DBCP with Play! Framework

Tags: playframework, apache-commons-dbcp

How can I set up my Play! app to use a commons-dbcp connection pool instead of
the native one provided by C3P0?

---

**UPDATE**

I got some feedback from the [Play! Framework forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/tk4sfVzVyDA) and what I was asking is achievable accessing a configured commons-DBCP DataSource via JNDI, e.g. when deploying the PLay! app in a container.

I'm still searching if I can utilize JNDI running the Play! app in the "default" environment.